# Redirecting a Makefile inside a cat heredocument vanishing variables and line breakes

Tags: shell, quoting, make, here-document

Executing:

```
cat <<MAKE >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/Makefile1
% :
    printf '%s\n' \
    '<VirtualHost *:80>' \
    'DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/$@">' \
    'ServerName $@' \
    '<Directory "/var/www/html/$@">' \
    'Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch' \
    'Require all granted' \
    '</Directory>' \
    'ServerAlias www.$@' \
    '</VirtualHost>' \
    > "$@"
    a2ensite "$@"
    systemctl restart apache2.service
    mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/$@ /etc/apache2/sites-available/$@.conf
    # Before quotes == Tabuilations. Inside quotes == Spaces. After quotes == Spaces (1 space before backslash for line break). Also avoid any other spaces.
MAKE
```

Creates this, after running `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/ && make contentperhour.com`:

```
% :
printf '%s\n' '<VirtualHost *:80>' 'DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/">' 'ServerName ' '<Directory "/var/www/html/">' 'Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch' 'Require all granted' '</Directory>' 'ServerAlias www.' '</VirtualHost>' > ""
a2ensite ""
systemctl restart apache2.service
mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/ /etc/apache2/sites-available/.conf
```

As you can see, after execution, the relevant line in the second example is just a long row (no line breaks, represented by backslashes, AND the variable `$@` doesn't appear anywhere. Why would this happen after redirecting?

Comment: are you not just seeing the usual shell substitution of ``\`` and `$` due to the unquoted word `MAKE`? try `cat <<\MAKE` or `cat <<"MAKE"` (or backslash escape ``\`` and `$`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `Here Documents` section of `man bash`

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>      <<[-]word
>             here-document
>      delimiter
> ```
>
> No  parameter  and variable expansion, command
>   substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed
>   on word.  If any  characters  in  word are quoted, the delimiter is
>   the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the
>   here-document are not expanded.  **If  word is  unquoted, all lines
>   of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the  charac‐ ter  sequence 
>   \  is  ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \,
>   $, and `.**

Since `MAKE` is unquoted in your example, `\` is ignored and `$@` is being expanded (to a presumably empty parameter list).

The solution is to quote (any part of) the marker e.g.

```
cat <<\MAKE >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/Makefile1
```

or

```
cat <<"MAKE" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/Makefile1
```

or to provide the required escapes e.g. `\\` for the line continuations and `\$@` for `$@`